# Extraer valor de un objeto dentro de otro objeto

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Tengo una duda, estoy trabajando en un proyecto con vue js en quasar, y tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
export const GETALUMNOS_API = async data => {
    const url = "/listadoAlumnos";
    try {
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve({data: [{ 
                rut: '19.221.546-4',
                nombre: 'Jorge Perez Gonzalez',
                carrera: 'Ingeniería comercial',
                matricula: '2016462090',
                puntaje: '450',
                email: 'Jr28284@gmail.com',
                plan: '15',
                datos_solicitud:[{
                    asi_nombre: 'Ingles l',
                    cur_nombre: 'Idioma Extranjero',
                    fecha_solicitud: '05/08/2021 13:35:01',
                    estado: 'Procesado'
                  }]},
```

quisiera extraer el valor fecha_solicitud que esta dentro de datos de solicitud para poder mostrarlo en una tabla, el código de mi tabla es el siguiente:

```
 columns : [
                    {
                      name: 'rut',
                      required: true,
                      label: 'Rut',
                      align: 'left',
                      field: row => row.name,
                  format: val => `${val}`
                },
               
            

{ name: 'nombre', label: 'Nombre', align: 'left', field: 'nombre', sortable: true},
            { name: 'carrera', label: 'Carrera', align: 'left', field: 'carrera', sortable: true},
            { name: 'matricula', label: 'Matricula', align: 'left', field: 'matricula', sortable: true },
            { name: 'puntaje', label: 'Puntaje Prioridad', align: 'left', field: 'puntaje', sortable: true },
            { name: 'modulos', label: 'Módulos', align: 'left', field: 'modulos', sortable: true},
            { name: 'fecha_solicitud', label: 'Fecha Actualización', align: 'left', field: '', sortable: true},
            { name: 'estado', label: 'Estado', align: 'left', field: 'estado', sortable: true},
           
        ],
```

quisiera saber como lo puedo cargar en la columna "fecha actualización" si alguien me puede dar la solución se lo agradecería mucho.

La función con la que llamo al objeto es la siguiente:

```
inicio(){
            
             this.$q.loading.show()

             this.$store.dispatch("listadoAlumnos/GETALUMNOS_ACTION",{}).then(res =>{
             console.log("RES",res)                        
             this.proptabla.items = res.data
             console.log("GETTER",this.GETALUMNOS_GETTER)
         
                this.$q.loading.hide()
             }).catch(err =>{
               console.error("ERROR: ", err)
                  this.$q.loading.hide()
              })
          
    },
```